# Calculate subtracts date in mysql for birthday event

Tags: php, mysql, events

i create a event for calculate a birthday , for example:

birthday date = 1990-09-07
now date = 2013-09-05

my query :

```
SELECT id FROM user WHERE ( birthday - NOW() ) <= 7
```

this query is mistake

Comment: If birthday was in `1990` and you subtract `NOW` from it, how do you expect it to be less than `7`?

Comment: What is 7? Days? months? Years? Seconds? - read this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: I am not even clear what you are trying to achieve, are you trying to find all users that have a birthday in the next 7 days?

Comment: yes , exactly . how to convert different of year, month , day ?

Comment: What `7`? You want reminder 7 days prior to birthday?

Comment: You need to read the link I posted. It gives enough information on how to measure differences / convert dates in any instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think DAYOFYEAR function is more suitable for you:

```
mysql> SELECT DAYOFYEAR('2000-09-07') - DAYOFYEAR(now()) AS diff;
+------+
| diff |
+------+
|    3 |
+------+
```

Today is 2013-09-05, it gave 3 days. Now you can compose the condition. Please, mind 1 day in the leap year.

Comment: @DipeshParmar No, I disagree. This http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofyear says, that the function returns in the range 1 to 366. BTW, the answer was accepted.

Comment: @DipeshParmar "well accepted answer does not meant that you are correct" - come on, range from 1 to 366 is unique for every day of the year.

Answer (score 2):

You said its for birthday so you must consider month and date as date can be repeat for every month..

So try something like below, **for year difference**.

```
SELECT
 (YEAR(birthdate) - YEAR(NOW())) AS yeardifference
FROM
 table
WHERE
  MONTH(birthdate) = MONTH(NOW())
AND
  DATEDIFF(birthdate, NOW()) <= 7
```

**For day difference**

```
SELECT
  DATEDIFF(birthdate, NOW())
FROM
  table
WHERE
  MONTH(birthdate) = MONTH(NOW())
AND
  DATEDIFF(birthdate, NOW()) <= 7
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your query should be something like

```
SELECT id 
FROM user 
WHERE (  DAYOFYEAR(birthday) - DAYOFYEAR(NOW())  <= 7)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Dayofyear function would be useful, just to put it in context with your requirement

```
SELECT id FROM user WHERE (DAYOFYEAR(birthday) - DAYOFYEAR(NOW()))  <= 7
```